# UISearchDisplayController causes crash after viewDidUnload

Tags: iphone, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uistoryboard

I have a project using StoryBoards and `UISearchDisplayController` used in the context of a `UINavigationController`, that appears in the root viewcontroller.  When I push a new view controller onto the stack and I cause a simulated memory warning (or actually get a low memory warning).  The previous view controller successfully unloads its view.  However, when I pop the second view controller off of the stack I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  I turned on NSZombies and discovered this:

> [UISearchDisplayController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb13aa30

I am not (at least in my code) sending that message to the `UISearchDisplayController`.  I am not doing anything, programmatically speaking, with it.  Break points reveal that I am not even making it into the `viewDidLoad` of the first view controller.

Something curious, though:  for laughs and giggles I decided to outright `retain` the SDC in my `viewDidLoad`, just to see what would happen and no crash occurs.  However, my `UISearchDisplayController` instance is `nil`.

I did a backtrace and get this output:

```
#0  0x01e30e1e in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x01e30ce2 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x01dd1490 in CFRetain ()
#3  0x01eb69c0 in +[__NSArrayI __new::] ()
#4  0x01e0a00a in -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] ()
#5  0x01e34f52 in +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] ()
#6  0x01e5e084 in -[NSDictionary allValues] ()
#7  0x01035272 in -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] ()
#8  0x00edce2c in -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] ()
#9  0x00edd3a9 in -[UIViewController loadView] ()
#10 0x00edd5cb in -[UIViewController view] ()
#11 0x00edd941 in -[UIViewController contentScrollView] ()
#12 0x00eef47d in -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] ()
#13 0x00eef66f in -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] ()
#14 0x00eef93b in -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] ()
#15 0x00ef03df in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] ()
#16 0x00ef16cb in _popViewControllerNormal ()
#17 0x00ef196c in -[UINavigationController _popViewControllerWithTransition:allowPoppingLast:] ()
#18 0x0b446e82 in -[UINavigationControllerAccessibility(SafeCategory) _popViewControllerWithTransition:allowPoppingLast:] ()
#19 0x00ef0b10 in -[UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:] ()
#20 0x00ef297d in -[UINavigationController navigationBar:shouldPopItem:] ()
#21 0x00e7dabe in -[UINavigationBar _popNavigationItemWithTransition:] ()
#22 0x00e7da49 in -[UINavigationBar popNavigationItemAnimated:] ()
#23 0x0b42208c in -[UINavigationBarAccessibility(SafeCategory) popNavigationItemAnimated:] ()
#24 0x00e80507 in -[UINavigationBar _handleMouseUpAtPoint:] ()
#25 0x00e8074c in -[UINavigationBar touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#26 0x00e3fa30 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#27 0x00e3fc56 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#28 0x00e26384 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#29 0x00e19aa9 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#30 0x02d37fa9 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#31 0x01e9e1c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#32 0x01e03022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#33 0x01e0190a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#34 0x01e00db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#35 0x01e00ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#36 0x02d36879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#37 0x02d3693e in GSEventRun ()
#38 0x00e17a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#39 0x00002b72 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff620)
```

There doesn't appear to be anything really interesting there (is there ever? :P) and appears to be all internals to Apple's stuff.  Any ideas on how to get this problem to go away?

**UPDATE:** Even when I remove the connection between my view controller and the property for the Search Display Controller but create my own `IBOutlet` for it, it still crashes.  Bad bug perhaps?

**UPDATE 2:** When I programmatically create my own instance of a `UISearchDisplayController` (not through the storyboard) and create it in `viewDidLoad`, everything works the way it is supposed to.

**UPDATE 3:** I am able to consistently reproduce this problem in a new project with a storyboard.  I did the same thing using a vanilla nib and everything worked the way it was suppose to.  However, if I setup the same thing using a storyboard and segue, it blows up just like it does in my real project.  :(

**RECAP**: Here are the steps in recreating this issue:

1. Create a view controller in a storyboard with a `UISearchDisplayController`
2. Push a new view controller on the navigation stack
3. Cause a low memory warning
4. Pop the controller off of the stack
5. ***KABOOM!***

`viewDidLoad` does not even get called on the first view controller at this point, Apple's code blows up before then.

Comment: What does your viewDidUnload method look like?

Comment: @aopsfan Just nil'ing out my `IBOutlets` and calling my super's implementation of `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: what happens if you remove that code?

Comment: I realize this could be a leak, but just to check...

Comment: did you set the IBOutlet to weak (ARC) or assign (no ARC)?

Comment: @relikd This is a non-ARC app.

Comment: I have the same issue, with ARC. If you are using a UITableViewController, you don't have to set an explicit IBOutlet -- the storyboard automatically sets it to self.searchDisplayController .

Comment: My XCode keeps crashing when I drop the component into view controller... First impression of the storyboard for me

Comment: Why don't you E-Mail apple developer technical support and see what they recommend in the mean time since they are the ones that created the problem in the first place.

Comment: @iBrad Apps - I have posted a Radar bug report.  My faith in the Apple dev forums is not very strong at all, so much so I don't even think it's worth my time posting there--seriously.

Comment: Nono - Apple Developer Technical Support. It is not a forum. It is where you get one on one help with an Apple developer for any issues you have. You get 2 requests per-year.

Comment: I'd like to duplicate this, what's your radar problem #?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what I did (granted, it's a workaround and not a fix for Apple's bug):

First, in a base `UIViewController` I created a property called `searchController`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchDisplayController* searchController;
```

I added a `UISearchBar` in through interface builder so that I have a placeholder in my UI for it.  Then, in my `viewDidLoad` I manually setup the controller and wire it up:

```
UISearchDisplayController* searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] 
                             initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
searchController.delegate = self;

self.searchController = searchController;
[searchController release];
```

In my `viewDidUnload` I make sure to clear it out:

```
self.searchController = nil;
```

Comment: You probably don't need to nil the entire `searchController`, just set it's `delegate` to nil.

Comment: @Mark Adams - Since I am `retain`ing the searchController in a property I am `nil`ing it out.  Objects that can easily be recreated in `viewDidLoad` should get zeroed out in `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: Fair enough. I was speaking in reference to your specific crash.

Comment: I don't understand how you're assigning your newly created `searchController` instance to `self.searchDisplayController` which is a read-only property.

Comment: @JohnTopley - Apologies. I updated my code example to point to a property that I created in my `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little? I don't quite understand what you're doing.

Comment: I actually read Wayne Liu's answer next, and it worked perfectly for me. Yours would probably make sense in a MRR environment, but I've moved on to ARC.

Comment: According to the documentation, the `viewDidUnload` method is deprecated and never called.

Comment: @VincentTourraine Sigh. Please take into consideration the date of the posting and the date that `viewDidUnload` officially became deprecated.

Comment: @WayneHartman Just for future reference, I believe it’s useful to point it out.

Answer (score 11):

So far, I found this working solution for iOS 5 SDK using ARC:

in .h file, declare your own searchDisplayController property with IBOutlet

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchDisplayController * searchDisplayController;
```

Then in the .m file, synthesize it:

```
@synthesize searchDisplayController;
```

But **don't** set it to nil in viewDidUnload.

So that the search display controller will use the property you create instead of using the inherited property.

I also notice the similar bug also appear for gesture recognizers (if you create gesture recognizers from the storyboard instead of creating them programmablly). We also need to create STRONG gesture recognizer properties and hook them with the gesture recognizer objects that you create in storyboard. Then in viewDidUnload, don't set them to nil. <-- this prevent the crashes.

Comment: Awesome, this one worked for me. This saved me hours (although I already had spend some of them to getting to this point ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use self.searchDisplayController only?

I have already used that many times it wont create any problem. You can also customize that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

@Wayne: I had run into the same issue with a SearchDisplayController created from a Storyboard, and spend over a day trying to debug a crash that seemed to appear when none of my code was running.  In my case the symptom was the user taps a tab in UITabBarController to return to a ViewController that has been unloaded after a memory warning.  The unloaded view controller's viewDidLoad method never runs and the code gets at least as far as tabBarController:didSelectViewController: (which should run *after* viewDidLoad) before it crashes somewhere in the assembly code!

Thanks massively for posting this workaround and for all the follow-ups. A small improvement is to move your UIDisplayController instantiation to a lazily loaded accessor method for the searchDisplayController property.  The practical effect is negligible but it looks nicer!

Answer (score 0):

An important point to note, is that crashes like this can occur if you leave the view whilst your searchDisplayController is still active. This is the issue I was having, selecting an item in the searchDisplayController was set to pop the view controller from the stack, in order to fix this, I had to include the following code before the view was popped...

```
if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {

        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Explicitly declare your outlet 

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;


Then in dealloc - add these lines - nil out the delegate / data source so that they do not receive any message further when the searchDisplayController deallocates itself.

self.searchDisplayController.delegate = nil;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = nil;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = nil;
```

Answer (score -1):

ViewDidUnload Called means, you got memory exceptions in your application.

First try to fix your memory issues, then automatically search display view controller problem will be resolved.

Because there seems to nothing wrong in code, When memory exceptions occurs, then better to take user previous screen by saying `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]`

Comment: There will inevitably be a situation at some point on someone's device where it is legitamately running out of memory, through no fault of my own as the developer.  The point of this question is to avoid the crash caused by *Apple's* mistake.  Calling `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]` will be of no use in this situation since this is one of the steps in recreating the issue.