# How can I re-load a searchDisplayController built in Storyboard, after a memory warning?

Tags: ios, memory-management, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uistoryboard

This project is for iPhone with iOS 5 using ARC and Core Data.

All built in Xcode Storyboards, I have a `UITabBarController` with a few tabs. Three of these views are `UITableViewControllers` with a `UISearchDisplayController` attached. If I simulate a memory warning in the iPhone simulator, whatever views are not active get dumped, and when I tap on the tab for one of these views with the searchDisplayController, NSZombieEnabled tells me `-[UISearchDisplayController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance`.

Here's my `-didReceiveMemoryWarning`:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [(PahAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] saveContext];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    self.searchWasActive = [self.searchDisplayController isActive];
    self.savedSearchTerm = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
    self.savedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    self.searchFetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    self.searchFetchedResultsController = nil;

    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

My best guess is that the `UITableViewController` dumps the subviews as well, and for whatever reason, it's not re-creating them when I go back to the other tabs. Since all of that functionality is built in Storyboard, I'm not quite sure how to go about requesting it re-load the `searchDisplayController` in question.

> Note: I've never seen the app do this in the real world on the device
>   (and neither have my beta testers), but I don't want Apple to refuse
>   approval of the app because of this; plus fixing it seems like The
>   Right Thing to Do.

`searchDisplayController` is a readonly property, so I'm not sure what tack to take to get things loaded like they should be.

Comment: Seems as if it may be a bug in Storyboard. Worked around for now by creating the `UISearchDisplayController` in code, as Brian Cooke suggests below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely seems like a, possibly Storyboards, bug. As mentioned here: [UISearchDisplayController causes crash after viewDidUnload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567525/uisearchdisplaycontroller-causes-crash-after-viewdidunload), a brand new project using Storyboards and a UISearchDisplayController can reproduce this without even connecting an outlet for the UISearchDisplayController into your controller. The suggestion in that thread seems sane, create the UISearchDisplayController in code. I can't vouch for the workaround as I didn't test it, but I was curious and did reproduce the new project = crash claim and saw the exact same thing.

Comment: I am coming to the same conclusion. I built a sample test project myself, just laying it out in Storyboard and not adding any custom code, and it still reproduces.

Comment: I add my answer to the other thread Brain mentioned. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567525/uisearchdisplaycontroller-causes-crash-after-viewdidunload/10734813#10734813