# SWRevealViewController -- app crashes on device

Tags: ios

I am using the SWRevealViewController (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) and the menu and the navigation works fine on the simulator. But when I run the same code on a device, the app crashes as soon as I pick any menu choice. I was wondering if anybody else has experienced a similar issue with this codebase running on a device.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please update your question with error?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on a UIView is what I am getting

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution to this

the root cause wasn't the SWRevealViewController

it had to do with search display controller, had to use the fix mentioned here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734813/740474)